# Extra space below header on mobile

Tags: html, css, header, spacing

https://codepen.io/Religion/pen/VwvNwRy thats the source code. The website looks fine when i'm on desktop spacing looks fine but that same code when shown on mobile becomes very spaced in between header and the title/start of the rest of the page. Wondering what I have to make it look the same when on mobile.

HTML:

```
<div class = "header-container">
        <div class = "video-container">
            <video preload = "true" autoplay = "autoplay" loop = "loop" muted = "muted" >
                <source src="https://d9nqqwcssctr8.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/26054225/VS20-DotCom-Header.mp4.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
                    <source src="https://d9nqqwcssctr8.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/26054238/VS20-DotCom-Header.webmhd.webm" type="video/webm"/>


            </video>
        </div>
        <div class = "head-section">
            <h2 class = "head-title">Ejad worship</h2>
            <a href="#" class="button btn1">Get to Know us better!</a>
        </div>   
    </div>

    <div class="about_area">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row align-items-center">
                <div class="col-xl-5 col-md-6">
                    <div class="about_thumb">
                        <img class="img-fluid" src="{% static 'website/img/about/rsz_15.png' %}" alt="">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xl-7 col-md-6">
                    <div class="about_info">
                        <h3>Part thats extra spaced</h3>
                        <p>Hey! We are glad you are here, visiting our website. </p>
                        <div class="signature">
                            <img src="{% static 'website/img/about/signature.png' %}" alt="">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.header-container{
  width:100%;
  height:900px;
  border-left:none;
  border-right:none;
  position:relative;
  padding:20px;
}


.video-container{
  position:absolute;
  top:0%;
  left:0%;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  overflow:hidden;
  z-index:-1;
}

video{
  position:absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  opacity:0.78;
  width:100%;

}

.head-section {

  z-index:1;
  text-align:center;
  margin-right:auto;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-top:15%;





}


.head-title {
  color:white;
   letter-spacing:3px;
  font-size:50px;
  font-family: "Josefin Sans", sans-serif;

}
.btn1 {
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.button {
    z-index:1;
    padding: 0.5em 10em;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    border: double 4px white;
    border-radius: 3px;
    transition: .4s;
    margin-bottom:-30;
}
.button:hover {
    background:white;
    opacity:50%;
}
.about_area {
  padding-bottom: 120px;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue is `video` object it is adjusting it self based on aspect ratio so you have to get rid of its width and adjust proper height to `header-container`

see demo below, it should work on desktop and mobile too - you can use media query if you want to limit code in mobile only

```css
.header-container{
  width:100%;
  height:900px;
  border-left:none;
  border-right:none;
  position:relative;
  padding:20px;
}


.video-container{
  position:absolute;
  top:0%;
  left:0%;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  overflow:hidden;
  z-index:-1;
}

video{
  position:absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  opacity:0.78;
  width:100%;

}

.head-section {
  
  z-index:1;
  text-align:center;
  margin-right:auto;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-top:15%;
  
  
 
 

}


.head-title {
  color:white;
   letter-spacing:3px;
  font-size:50px;
  font-family: "Josefin Sans", sans-serif;

}
.btn1 {
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.button {
    z-index:1;
    padding: 0.5em 10em;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    border: double 4px white;
    border-radius: 3px;
    transition: .4s;
    margin-bottom:-30;
}
.button:hover {
    background:white;
    opacity:50%;
}
.about_area {
  padding-bottom: 120px;
  
}


/* updated code */
body {
    margin: 0;
}

.button {
    padding: 10px 30px;
}

video {
    width: auto;
}

.header-container {
    height: 100vh;
    padding: 20px 0;
}
.head-section{
    margin-bottom: 15%;
 }
```

```html
<div class = "header-container">
        <div class = "video-container">
            <video preload = "true" autoplay = "autoplay" loop = "loop" muted = "muted" >
                <source src="https://d9nqqwcssctr8.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/26054225/VS20-DotCom-Header.mp4.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
                    <source src="https://d9nqqwcssctr8.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/26054238/VS20-DotCom-Header.webmhd.webm" type="video/webm"/>
                        

            </video>
        </div>
        <div class = "head-section">
            <h2 class = "head-title">Ejad worship</h2>
            <a href="#" class="button btn1">Get to Know us better!</a>
        </div>   
    </div>
    
    <div class="about_area">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row align-items-center">
                <div class="col-xl-5 col-md-6">
                    <div class="about_thumb">
                        <img class="img-fluid" src="{% static 'website/img/about/rsz_15.png' %}" alt="">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xl-7 col-md-6">
                    <div class="about_info">
                        <h3>Ejad Worship</h3>
                        <p>This title and paragraph extra spaced on mobile</p>
                        <div class="signature">
                            <img src="{% static 'website/img/about/signature.png' %}" alt="">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: took a bit messing around after adding that code but i think the main issue was the video width. thanks so much for answer the problem had me stumbled for over a day